# Should I Disavow irrelevant links targeting my blog through Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, backlinks

I commented on a blog, and after some days I checked my Google Webmaster Tools and I found an issue which is similar to ReplytoCom ( Reply to comment ), that means I am not only getting one nofollow link to my blog but accompanied with 35 more irrelevant links. Should I Disvow those 35 links as it may be SPAM in the eyes of Google?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, "irrelevant" links are fine. The main problem is when you get links that are from a website that itself is a spam site (or a genuine site with loads of spam comments.) Otherwise, you'll end up spending more time in Webmaster Tools than on your site, where it would definitively be of more value.

Comment: To follow on from @Alexis Wilke's answer - do not use the disavow file if you do not know what it is for or how to use it. It is purely only for disavowing domains or pages containing backlinks to your website that Google would deem low quality, spammy or that you wouldn't vouch for. Failure to use the disavow tool correctly can result in disastrous consequences.